# Why does the following regex for matching integers does not work as expected?

Tags: python, regex

The following code in Python:

```
pattern = r'(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+'
text = "Here are some numbers: 10, 201."
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(matches)
```

prints:

```
['0', '1']
```

why does it not print ['10', '201']?

Comment: You want `[0-9]+`, your regex is one of those characters repeated one or more times, so it will match `0` and `00` but not `10` or `201`

Comment: Isn't (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+ equivalent to [0-9]+?

Comment: your matching all the numbers but due to how you have setup your capture group your only getting the last digit of each match since your group is only a single digit

Comment: @SanyoMn no - a repeated capture group *only* captures the last occurrence. That's why you're seeing `0` and `1` (the last digits of `10` and `201`) as the result. To get the same as `[0-9]+`, just remove the capturing group: `re.findall(r'(?:0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+', text)`

Comment: I'm more curious why it didn't return `1,0,2,0,1`

Comment: @OneCricketeer for that you would just need `re.findall(r'0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9', text)` (no capturing group), matching only a single character at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just breaking down your regex and explaining it in a bit more detail

```
r'(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)+'
```

Is going to match all continuous strings of digits but your capture group (the stuff in between `()`) is only a single digit so for each continuous strings of digits only the last digit is captured and saved. (in regex matching is not the same as capture groups, your logic was not incorrect just the setup of the capture group)

If you want to get whole digit strings out in your regex match you can simply use a pattern like

```
r'(\d+)'
```

which matches any digits. (it is the same as using `[0-9]+`)

Comment: Just to make it clear: `findall` has surprising behavior — it depends on whether your pattern has 0, 1 or more capture groups. If your capture groups are meant for grouping and not for capturing, you should enclose your whole pattern in another capture group